# How to type open and close braces such that includes inside of some rows of tabular

Tags: tables, amsmath

I want to type a table having some open and close braces but I have a problem with including open and close braces such that they include different rows of the table. In fact, I tried to type the following table
[image]
but I just could provide the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}   % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % math-mode version of "l" column type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % math-mode version of "l" column type
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} % math-mode version of "l" column type
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{CCCCCCC}  
\hline \hline
& S  &  L  & J^{P}  & \text{Symmetry} & \text{Notation} & \text{Isospin} \, T \\
\hline
& 1 & 0 & 1^+ & \text{symmetric} & ^3 \text{S}_1 & \\
& 1 & 2 & 1^+,2^+,3^+ & \text{in} & ^3 \text{D}_{1,2,3} & \\
\text{NP only}&&&&&& 0\\
& 0 & 1 & 1^- & \text{spin} +  \text{position} & ^1 \text{P}_1 & \\
& 0 & 3 & 3^- &  & ^1 \text{F}_3 & \\ \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\text{NN} & 1 & 1 & 0^-, 1^-, 2^- & \text{antisymmetric} & ^3 \text{P}_{0,1,2} & \\
\text{PP} & 1 & 3 & 2^-, 3^-, 4^- &  & ^3 \text{F}_{2,3,4} & \\
&&&&\text{in}&& 1 \\
\text{and} & 0 & 0 & 0^+ & & ^1\text{S}_0 & \\
\text{NP} & 0 & 2 & 2^+ & \text{spin} + \text{position} & ^1 \text{D}_2 & \\
\hline \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

which gives me

[image]

How can I type the open and close braces in the tabular?

Comment: Take a look at the `bigdelim` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two suggestions using the `bigdelim` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}   % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % math-mode version of "l" column type
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{rCCCCCc}  
\hline \hline
& S  &  L  & J^{P}  & \text{Symmetry} & \text{Notation} & \text{Isospin} \, T \\
\hline
\ldelim\{{5}{1.5cm}[NP only] & 1 & 0 & 1^+ & \multirow{5}{*}{\makecell{symmetric\\ in\\ spin + position}} & ^3 \text{S}_1 & \rdelim\}{5}{0.5cm}[0]\\
& 1 & 2 & 1^+,2^+,3^+ &  & ^3 \text{D}_{1,2,3} & \\
&&&&&& \\
& 0 & 1 & 1^- &  & ^1 \text{P}_1 & \\
& 0 & 3 & 3^- &  & ^1 \text{F}_3 & \\ \hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \ldelim\}{5}{1.5cm}[\makecell{NN\\ PP \\ \\ and \\ NP}] \rdelim\{{5}{5pt} & 1 & 1 & 0^-, 1^-, 2^- & \multirow{5}{*}{\makecell{antisymmetric\\ in\\ spin + position}} & ^3 \text{P}_{0,1,2} & \rdelim\}{5}{0.5cm}[1]\\
 & 1 & 3 & 2^-, 3^-, 4^- &  & ^3 \text{F}_{2,3,4} & \\
&&&&&&  \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0^+ & & ^1\text{S}_0 & \\
 & 0 & 2 & 2^+ &  & ^1 \text{D}_2 & \\
\hline \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{rCCCCCc}  
\toprule
& S  &  L  & J^{P}  & \text{Symmetry} & \text{Notation} & Isospin T \\
\midrule
\ldelim\{{4}{1.5cm}[NP only] & 1 & 0 & 1^+ & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{symmetric\\ in\\ spin + position}} & ^3 \text{S}_1 & \rdelim\}{4}{0.5cm}[0]\\
& 1 & 2 & 1^+,2^+,3^+ &  & ^3 \text{D}_{1,2,3} & \\
& 0 & 1 & 1^- &  & ^1 \text{P}_1 & \\
& 0 & 3 & 3^- &  & ^1 \text{F}_3 & \\ \midrule
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \ldelim\}{4}{1.5cm}[\makecell{NN\\ PP \\  and \\ NP}] \rdelim\{{4}{5pt} & 1 & 1 & 0^-, 1^-, 2^- & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{antisymmetric\\ in\\ spin + position}} & ^3 \text{P}_{0,1,2} & \rdelim\}{4}{0.5cm}[1]\\
 & 1 & 3 & 2^-, 3^-, 4^- &  & ^3 \text{F}_{2,3,4} & \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0^+ & & ^1\text{S}_0 & \\
 & 0 & 2 & 2^+ &  & ^1 \text{D}_2 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another version, using  `booktabs`, `bigdelim` and `delarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs} % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % math-mode version of "l" column type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % math-mode version of "c" column type
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} % math-mode version of "r" column type
\usepackage{multirow, bigdelim, delarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c@{}CCCCC@{}c@{}C}
\toprule \midrule
  & S & L & J^{P} & \text{Symmetry} & \text{Notation} & & \text{Isospin} \, T \\
\midrule[0.4pt]
 \ldelim\{{5}{*}[NP only\ ] & 1 & 0 & 1^+ & \text{symmetric} & ^3 \text{S}_1 & \rdelim\}{5}{*}\\
  & 1 & 2 & 1^+,2^+,3^+ & \text{in} & ^3 \text{D}_{1,2,3} & \\
 &&&&&& & 0\\
 & 0 & 1 & 1^- & \text{spin} + \text{position} & ^1 \text{P}_1 & \\
 & 0 & 3 & 3^- & & ^1 \text{F}_3 & \\
\addlinespace[2ex]%\hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ldelim\{{5}{*}[\begin{tabular}.{@{}l}\}NN \\PP\\ \\and\\NP \end{tabular}\enspace] & 1 & 1 & 0^-, 1^-, 2^- & \text{antisymmetric} & ^3 \text{P}_{0,1,2} & \rdelim\}{5}{*}\\
 & 1 & 3 & 2^-, 3^-, 4^- & & ^3 \text{F}_{2,3,4} & \\
 &&&&\text{in}&& & 1 \\
& 0 & 0 & 0^+ & & ^1\text{S}_0 & \\
 & 0 & 2 & 2^+ & \text{spin} + \text{position} & ^1 \text{D}_2 & \\
\midrule[0.4pt] \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]